# How to remove duplicates Id and names from the csv file in c# winform before import to datagrid or datatable

Tags: c#

Here is my code now its removing only duplicate ID but I want to remove duplicate ID and Name from the row 
This is my CSV file
[image]
I want remove duplicates like this before import
[image]

> Remove duplicates from CSV before import

```
          namespace Export_Import_CSV
         {
         public partial class Form1 : Form
         {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindDataGridView();
        }
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         private void ImportBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt.Rows.Clear();
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Multiselect = true;
            if (DialogResult.OK == dlg.ShowDialog())
            {
                string path = dlg.FileName;
                // BindData(path);
                AddCSVDataToGrid(path);
                MessageBox.Show("Import Action Completed");
            }
        }
                 private void BindData(string filePath)
        {
            string[] Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            string[] lines = Lines.Distinct().ToArray();
            if (Lines.Length != lines.Length)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("duplicates data found,Ignored duplicates data from csv file");
            }
            if (lines.Length > 0)
            {
                string[] dataWords;
                DataRow dr;
                for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    dataWords = lines[i].Split(',');
                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    int totCols = dt.Columns.Count;
                    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < totCols; colIndex++)
                    {
                        dr[colIndex] = dataWords[colIndex];
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide what your definition of “duplicate” is and how you “decide” which item is a duplicate. Example, if your definition of “duplicate” is _“ID AND Name”_ … then there are no duplicates in your posted data. “1, Manish, Pandey” and “3, Manish, Pandey” would not be considered “duplicate” since one ID is 1 and the other is a 3. The same would apply to “4, William… and 3, William…”

Comment: Another conundrum, is if you do determine that “1, Manish, Pandey” and “3, Manish, Pandey” are duplicates because the names are the same, then how do you “decide” which one to throw away? Should the ID be 1 or 3? This same idea would apply to the 3 and 4 “william sor” names. Can you describe how you define a duplicate and how you decide on which one to keep. Obviously if both have the same “exact” ID and Name then it will not matter which one you remove unless you want to include the country. Can you clarify any of this?

Comment: My requirement is like that ID should be unique and Remaining columns data of that particular row data aslo unique for example 1 ,Manish, Pandey, Morroco
with this same data no duplicate. Even i dont know how to do like this if ID should be unique means will use Distict or loops to remove.Please hep on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using two `HashSet`s (one for `Id` and one for the name) we can check if an ID or name had already come up.

```cs
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
HashSet<int> IDs = new HashSet<int>()
HashSet<string> Names = new HashSet<string>();
bool hasError = false;

string[] dataWords;
DataRow dr;
for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    dataWords = lines[i].Split(',');
    int ID = int.Parse(dataWords[0]);
    string name = dataWords[1] + " " + dataWords[2];
    if (IDs.Contains(ID) || Names.Contains(name)
    {
        hasError = true;
        continue;
    }
    IDs.Add(ID);
    Names.Add(name);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    int totCols = dt.Columns.Count;
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < totCols; colIndex++)
    {
        dr[colIndex] = dataWords[colIndex];
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

if (hasError)
{
    MessageBox.Show("duplicates data found,Ignored duplicates data from csv file");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Make Sure you have trimmed the line when appending in list

```
string[] Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
 string[] lines = Lines.Distinct().ToArray();
 string[] duplicateLines = Lines.Except(lines);

if(duplicateLines.Count()>0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("duplicates data found,Ignored duplicates data from csv file");
}
```